# Updating a field by looking up same field in another table

Tags: sql, vlookup, name-lookup

I have 3 tables:
Regtable
finaltable
ptable

I want to update a QTRcontractend field in finaltable  with QTRcontractend field in REGtable if ID from finaltable is present in regtable

I have written the below code but get an error that my subquery has returned multiple values.how do I select only one value

```
update a
set QTRofcontractend = case when a.ID in (select ID from Regtable) then  
 (select contractendQTR from Regtable as org where ID = org.ID)
                  when a.ID in (select ID from ptable) then '0' 
                  when a.ID in (select ID from Regtable) then '0' 
                  else '--' end
 from finaltable as a
```

Thanks and Regards,
Nishanth Baskaran

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: You know, joining would be a lot easier for you. Also, that last `WHEN` is redundant because of the first one.